# How to display custom error pages with JSF and Quarkus?

Tags: java, jsf, quarkus

I am trying to display custom error pages for different status codes (401, 404, 500, ...) in JSF (myfaces version: 2.3-next-M3).
I am using a Quarkus Application Server (1.5.2.Final) with JDK 8.

At the moment the default Quarkus Internal Server Error HTML page will be displayed, if an exception occurs. If a resource could not be found the application server will display the entered path to the not existing resource. But I want to display my own custom error pages.

I already tried:

web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

and

Provider Bean:

```
@Provider
public class NotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException exception) {
        String text = new Scanner(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/resources/error/404.xhtml"), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        return Response.status(404).entity(text).build();
    }
}
```

But nothing worked. Am I missing something?
What can I do to display my custom error pages?

Comment: This is not really related to to quarkus. JSF doesnt use error-page in web.xml per default. You need a own exception-handler or https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/9_0/#/core/errorhandling

Comment: @tandraschko When I try to include the el-resolver and exception-handler-factory to my faces-config, I get this error when I start the quarkus server: `Class org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver not found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:`

Comment: then you dont use primefaces?

Comment: @tandraschko I am currently using Primefaces 8.0 as well as the primefaces-extension. My complete UI depends on primefaces ui components. I can even find the PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver by myself, if I look for it via my IDE.

Comment: can you try to replicate it in the myfaces-quarkus-showcase?

Comment: @tandraschko I wasn't able to start the showcase. But I pushed a minimal example in my git repo: [https://github.com/lefab25/custom-error-page-example]

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-4355 - should also work with the current version if you remove the newlines/blank spaces inside the el-resolver tag